# Laravel Eloquent - Getting data from related models and apply union doesn't work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, union

Faced a really strange error and can't understand why it's happening. Please see the explanation below to understand the issue!

**What I have:**

- 3 models: *Bucket*, *Template* and *DesignPack*.
- *Bucket* has Many-To-Many(Polymorphic) relationship with *Template* and *DesignPack*(It means we have pivot table *bucketables*).
- In essence *Bucket* can have(be related with) both: *Template* and *DesignPack*.
- Laravel 6.*

**What I want to do:**

- I want to get all Bucket's Template and DesignPack models merged(using union) with specific columns only. Want to get it with pagination also off course as we can have too many items :)

**What I did:** 
I tried a few solutions but none of the worked, had the same errors. Please see example below what I've tried:

```
    $templates = Bucket::find($bucket_id)->templates()->select('id', 'file_name as name', 'size', 'preview');
    $design_packs = Bucket::find($bucket_id)->dps()->select('id', 'name', 'size', 'preview');

    $bt_uploads = $templates->union($design_packs)->paginate(20);

    return UserUploadResource::collection($bt_uploads);
```

**The error I get constantly is:**

> "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT
>   statements have a different number of columns (SQL: select count(*) as
>   aggregate from ((select `id`, `file_name` as `name`, `size`,
>   `preview`, `templates`.*, `bucketables`.`bucket_id` as
>   `pivot_bucket_id`, `bucketables`.`bucketable_id` as
>   `pivot_bucketable_id`, `bucketables`.`bucketable_type` as
>   `pivot_bucketable_type` from `templates` inner join `bucketables` on
>   `templates`.`id` = `bucketables`.`bucketable_id` where
>   `bucketables`.`bucket_id` = 3 and `bucketables`.`bucketable_type` =
>   App\Template and `templates`.`deleted_at` is null) union (select `id`,
>   `name`, `size`, `preview` from `design_packs` inner join `bucketables`
>   on `design_packs`.`id` = `bucketables`.`bucketable_id` where
>   `bucketables`.`bucket_id` = 3 and `bucketables`.`bucketable_type` =
>   App\DesignPack and `design_packs`.`deleted_at` is null)) as
>   `temp_table`)"

Many thanks guys for any help and ideas!